# Time/Space complexity for my novel Swim in Rising Water leetcode solution

Tags: java, time, time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory

I submitted the following code for the [Swim in Rising Water](https://leetcode.com/problems/swim-in-rising-water/description/) question on Leetcode.

```
class Solution {
    int[][]grid;
    boolean[][]visited;
    HashMap<Integer,Deque<Pair<Integer,Integer>>> higher;
    public int swimInWater(int[][] grid) {
        this.grid=grid;
        Deque<Pair<Integer,Integer>> dq = new ArrayDeque<>();
        dq.add(new Pair<>(0,0));
        this.visited = new boolean[grid.length][grid[0].length];
        //find max in grid and run bfs until it returns better than 0
        int max=0;
        visited[0][0]=true;
        this.higher = new HashMap<>();
        higher.put(grid[0][0],dq);
        
        for (int i=0;i<grid.length;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<grid[0].length;j++) {
                max=Math.max(grid[i][j],max);
            }
        }
        for (int i=grid[0][0];i<=max;i++) {
            if (higher.containsKey(i)&&bfs(i,higher.get(i))) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
    public boolean bfs(int tolerance, Deque<Pair<Integer,Integer>> dq){
        while (dq.size()>0) {
            int len=dq.size();
            Pair<Integer,Integer> value = dq.poll();
            int left=value.getKey();
            int right=value.getValue();
            for (int idx=0;idx<len;idx++) {
                if (left==grid.length-1&&right==grid.length-1) {
                    return true;
                }
                for (int i=Math.max(0,left-1);i<=Math.min(left+1,grid.length-1);i++) {
                    for (int j=Math.max(0,right-1);j<=Math.min(right+1,grid[0].length-1);j++) {
                        if (Math.abs(i-left)!=Math.abs(j-right)&&!visited[i][j]) {
                            visited[i][j]=true;
                            if (grid[i][j]<=tolerance) {
                                dq.add(new Pair<>(i,j));
                            } else  {
                                Pair<Integer,Integer> coordPair = new Pair<>(i,j);
                                if (higher.containsKey(grid[i][j])) {
                                    higher.get(grid[i][j]).add(coordPair);
                                } else {
                                    Deque<Pair<Integer,Integer>> newdq = new ArrayDeque<>();
                                    newdq.add(coordPair);
                                    higher.put(grid[i][j],newdq);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I believe this possesses a time complexity of O(N^2+M), where N is the size of a side of the grid and M is the max value within it, as the visited array prevents the breadth-first search from considering a coordinate multiple times. However this code only beats 18.95% of all other users, and most solutions to this problem run in O(N^2log(N)) time or worse. Am I correct? Also, is my calculation of O(N^2+M) space complexity accurate?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place for this question.